# AS3 how to go to next frame in MainTimeline when character die animation ends

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

so I need to know if my character(bird) hitTestObject with pipe he plays the die animation after the animation ends it need to go to the game over frame in the main timeline

```
if (bird.hitTestObject(pipe1)) {

 bird.gotoAndStop(3); //frame 3 = where the die animation is 

}
```

LINK 1 (here you see different frames for animations frame 3 is die animation)
http://gyazo.com/67381832827bfb8a4dac2452076a4217

LINK 2 (the die animation) 
http://gyazo.com/bf5153a9d00e1478471fff7b73d0c592

so here you can see the animation in the end of the animation there need code to go to game over frame in the main timeline frame 3

btw its not in a .as file but in the timeline

thank you if you can help me and if my english is not good sorry about that im dutch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an enter frame event, like so:

```
if (bird.hitTestObject(pipe1)) {

    bird.gotoAndStop(3); //frame 3 = where the die animation is 
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, waitForDeathAnimationToEnd);

}

function waitForDeathAnimationToEnd(e:Event)
{
    if(bird.currentFrame === bird.totalFrames)
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, waitForDeathAnimationToEnd);
        bird.stop();
        gotoAndStop(frameOrFrameLabelWhereYourGameOverFrameIs); //Replace with Game Over frame label or number
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have skype or something so i can send you the file there is still a problem with it

Comment: @OneshotFire Yeah, send it to my email... it's in my profile description

Comment: i sended it to your email